# Pandas count based on condition in current row from records before current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe show as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c']})
df.sort_values('col1', inplace=True)
df['Ref']=0
```

Thus the dataframe looks like:

```
a  0
a  0
a  0
b  0
b  0
c  0
```

For the ref column, I want to show the number of reference of current row. For illustration purpose, following is what I want to achieve:

```
a  0
a  1
a  2
b  0
b  1
c  0
```

I can use df.iterrows() and loop row by row. Un fortunately in my case, it will take 15 minutes to run. I am wondering if there is a reasonable way to do so.

Comment: Can we assume `df['col1']` is ordered? Or is `[a,a,b,a,b]` possible, but requiring the same results?

Comment: Yes you can assume it is sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Group the data by `col1` and use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c']})

df['Ref'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
    
df.sort_values('col1', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

  col1  Ref
0    a    0
1    a    1
2    a    2
3    b    0
4    b    1
5    c    0
```